# Using "AS" in MySQL - not as aliases

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I was kinda surprised when I saw following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE X (ID int) AS SELECT NumColumn FROM Table
```

I have tried to google it but only found using this as alieases. What this use actually is? I feel bit confused since I was stupidly creating temporary table and then fill it by using of insert..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its how you create a temporary table and populate it with the results of a select query.

You can see it [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) at the very bottom of the CREATE TABLE specification

> select_statement:
>       [IGNORE | REPLACE] [AS] SELECT ...   (Some legal select statement)

Answer (score 1):

This will create a temporary table for you but just remember that this will not bring along any indexes you had on the original table.   For that reason, sometimes it may be better create a complete copy of the table definition using

```
create table x like y;
```

Since this only creates an EMPTY table, you need to also run

```
insert into x (col1) select col1 from y;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE (table name) AS SELECT * FROM (existing table name);`

this command for copy whole table in to another table;