# Temporary table creation

Tags: php, mysql

I am debuging php website and don't know how mysql query in it works. The code is:

```
$query = "
        SELECT
            WR.*,           
            W.*,
            D.*         
        FROM
            {#table} WR
        LEFT JOIN words W
            ON WR.word_id = W.word_id
        LEFT JOIN words_descriptions WD
            ON W.word_id = WD.word_id
        LEFT JOIN descriptions D
            ON WD.description_id = D.description_id
        " . $user_words_sql . "
        WHERE 
            title_len > 3
            AND W.in_game = 1
            " . $frequency_sql . " 
            " . $type_sql . "   
        GROUP BY 
            WR.word_id, 
            WR.description_id               
        ORDER BY
            $additional_order W.frequency DESC      
    ";
```

My question is where table WR is created, is it temporary table created in this peace of code or is it created somewhere else? Also, what this expression `{#table}` does?

Comment: I'm guessing that `{#table}` is a tag that gets replaced later on in the code. And read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471343/using-as-in-mysql-not-as-aliases) about temporary tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value "WR" is an alias for the query, not a temporary table. It doesn't copy the data in memory, it's just a shortcut to make the query shorter/easier to read. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM countries c WHERE c.code = "GB"
```

Expands to be:

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE countries.code = "GB"
```

@machineaddict was correct, the {#table} has no significance in MySQL - it's likely that this is being replaced at a later stage by another part of your PHP application.

Comment: You are right about temporary names. My mistake. Anyway, mysql documentation website is a complete mess, it is very unreadable.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpfull!